# How to plug consensus in Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am learning hyperledger fabric
How to change the consensus mechanism in hyperledger fabric implementation.
What does it mean by pluggable consensus in the first place?
Is it possible for us to change the consensus mechanism or we have to use only the available consensus mechanisms given in the documentation.
can anyone give some comments on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I myself found answers for some of the questions posted...

- For changing the Consensus mechanism in the hyperledger fabric, go to the configtx file of the hyperledger fabric and choose any of the two available consensus mechanisms such as KAFKA or SOLO.
- Pluggable consensus means that the way nodes in the network are communicating is being implemented using a method or procedure called consensus. An efficient consensus protocol would add to the performance of the system.
- Since hyperledger is an opensource implementation, we can download the hypderledger fabric on to our system and get our own method of implementation of consensus.
- To my knowledge, IBM and other organizations are trying to develop other mechanisms also for consensus to plug into Hyperledger Fabric.

Comment: Do you have any reference or something about, how to implement a consensus for hyperledger?

Comment: As such you cannot have provision for implementing your own consensus algorithm in hyperledger, but you can play with various available existing consensus protocols that hyperledger supports by plugging in/out. You may checkout the paper: https://www.hyperledger.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/Hyperledger_Arch_WG_Paper_1_Consensus.pdf

Comment: Thank you. I have already read that. But, in frequently asked questions of hyperledger-fabric, at the end, I found a one which explain how to plug an own consensus. Still didn't find that anyone has try that before.  https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.0/Fabric-FAQ.html

Comment: Yeah, I get it. I mean, you cannot start one from scratch on your own on top of hyperledger. As the FAQ suggests, you need to use the consenter and orderer packages to build your own consensus in line with their design structure. They, in fact, give reference to the raft protocol implementation. That is quite handy for developing/plugging own consensus. As you said, I have not tried it as it would be time consuming. But it is worth it unless you are in academic environment and time is a constraint for the target.

Comment: Actually it is an academic thing. I only need to enhance a paxos(consensus) algorithm on top of a permissioned ledger. I only found 2 options, 1) use the hyperledger-fabric and make a custom consensus, or 2) use distAlgo to implement the algorithm and setup it on own permissioned ledger. I think, implementing an own permissioned ledger is worse than that. Is there, any suggestions?

Comment: I think plugging your own consensus in hyperledger private permissioned ledger is better than the other option you've mentioned. But it would be ideal to have group working on this. You may refer to this, how hedera consensus is plugged into hyper ledger. https://www.hyperledger.org/blog/2020/05/14/new-to-the-hyperledger-labs-pluggable-hedera-consensus-service

I may ask experts in this area in my circle and get back to you. If any help I can give further.

Comment: That would be a great support. Thank you.